# Huge performance difference in almost identical queries

Tags: mysql, performance, phpmyadmin, myisam

I have two queries to count the number of rows in a relatively large table. To allow for filtering by a particular name, I've left-joined a smaller table to it.

My first attempt yielded query #1 (see below), which turned out to be very, very slow (6-7 seconds). After playing around with the query for a bit, I got to query #2 (see below) which seems to do the same thing much faster (< 0.05 seconds).

Query #1 ( > 6 seconds):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM bigtable
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT LocalKey, Name
    FROM smalltable
) AS smalltable ON bigtable.ForeignKey = smalltable.LocalKey;
```

Query #2 ( < 0.05 seconds):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM bigtable
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT LocalKey, Name
    FROM smalltable
) AS smalltable ON bigtable.ForeignKey = smalltable.LocalKey
WHERE smalltable.LocalKey LIKE "%";
```

Both queries return the exact same number (50300).
`bigtable` has 50300 rows, `smalltable` has 680 rows. To remove as many factors as possible, I've ensured that all records in `bigtable` have a (unique) matching row in `smalltable`. 
`smalltable.LocalKey` is indexed, as well as the primary key for `bigtable`. Both tables have been optimised using `OPTIMIZE TABLE [table];`. All rows from `smalltable` are matched by `smalltable.LocalKey LIKE "%"`.

I've tried searching for this phenomenon exhaustively, however, I've found no explanations for it whatsoever. Does anyone have an explanation for why the first query is so much slower, and, if possible, a better solution than query #2?

Edit:

[Explain Extended for query #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttJOs.png)

[Explain Extended for query #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdib5.png)

Comment: The second query is an inner join

Comment: Please generate [Execution Plan Information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) for both queries and append them to the question (just run :`EXPLAIN EXTENDED your_query`).

Comment: I've added the Execution Plan infomation.

If the second is an inner join, is it possible to achieve the effect of a left join without the performance penalty?

Comment: Maybe it's me, or you've over generalized your example query, but what exactly is the purpose of the join to begin with? In the first query, you could've just counted the rows in big table.

Comment: I've over generalized it somewhat, I want to be able to filter by the smalltable.Name field.  I'd still like it to count correctly when no constraints are set for the Name field, though.

Comment: That's interesting.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both queries.  Also `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for both.

Comment: By using `LEFT`, you are not filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after running each query, SHOW $WARNINGS will show you the OPTIMIZED query execution order.  Posting the SHOW $WARNINGS for query #1 and query #2 should help us understand why query #2 is so much quicker.

Comment: No `$`.  Just `SHOW WARNINGS;`